# jOOQ update a JSON array field using a String

Tags: java, jooq

I have a JSON Array field (`Array<JSONB?>`) (in Postgres its a JSONB[]) that contains a value like so:

Before: `[{"key1":"val1"}, {"key2":"val2"}]`

I want to perform an update on this array - to do a simple string replace (*val* to *value*). Yes: I want to treat the JSON array as a string, but save back into the DB as a JSON array.

After:
`[{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}]`

I am finding it hard to get the syntax with JOOQ correct. I have the following:

```kotlin
val jsonArrayAsString = record.getValue(MY_TABLE.ARRAY_FIELD).contentDeepToString().replace("val", "value")))

conn.update(MY_TABLE).set(MY_TABLE.ARRAY_FIELD, jsonArrayAsString))
```

Comment: in raw SQL this looks like `update my_table
set column = replace(column::text, 'val', 'value')::jsonb[]
 `

Answer (score 0):

You can translate a lot of native SQL to jOOQ, in your case, this (from your comments):

```sql
-- SQL
replace(column::text, 'val', 'value')::jsonb[]
```

Would just be

```java
// jOOQ
replace(MY_TABLE.COLUMN.cast(CLOB), "val", "value").cast(JSONB.getArrayDataType())

// Starting from jOOQ 3.18, there will be an alias JSONB.array()
```

But you don't have to translate everything to jOOQ API if you feel that something would be simpler to express in native SQL. Just use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), in that case:

```java
field("replace({0}::text, 'val', 'value')::jsonb[]", 
    MY_TABLE.COLUMN.getDataType(), 
    MY_TABLE.COLUMN
)
```

Assuming, as always, the usual static imports:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.*;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Something I still don't understand: it is not possible to use `replace` and `field` inside the `.set` function (remember I am trying to perform an update operation). The docs only show `replace` and `field` being used inside `select` functions.

Comment: @john: Did you try it? Have you checked out the API (in the IDE / Javadoc, etc) and the available `set()` methods? What made you think it wouldn't work?